# If measure of $f >n$ is zero, show $f<\infty$ almost everywhere.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f: S \to [0, \infty]$ be a measurable function. Suppose that
$$
\lim _{n \to \infty} \mu\{f>n\}=0.
$$
Prove that $f< \infty$ almost everywhere.

**My try**

Suppose to the contrary that $f<\infty$ is not true almost everywhere. Then there exists a set $N \in S$ such that $f=\infty$ and $\mu(N)\neq 0$.

**My concern**

Can I write the following?

$$
\lim _{n \to \infty} \mu\{f>n\}=\mu\{f> \lim _{n \to \infty} n\}=\mu\{f=\infty\}
$$

If so, then I can say that is contraction to $\mu(N)=0$ and I am done.

**Question**

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your initial attempt is on the right track, but you can’t pull the limit inside the measure since it’s not necessarily continuous.

You can say that $\mu(f>n) \ge \mu(f= \infty) \ge 0$ since one set is a subset of the other. Then, taking the limit gives the desired result.

Comment: Can you please complete the steps for me?

Comment: What steps? You literally stick a limit on it, it gives you that the set where it’s infinite is measure 0, so it’s a.s. finite.

Comment: Note that $\{x \mid f(x)= \infty \} = \cap_n \{x \mid f(x) >n \}$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Can you please give a proof based on the intersection of sets?

Comment: @ProcessOptimizer You need to do some work. $0 \le \mu \{x \mid f(x)= \infty \} \le \mu \{x \mid f(x) >n \}$ for all $n$. Now use the fact that $\lim_n \mu \{x \mid f(x) >n \} = 0$ to conclude.